# Solidity - initialize string array in struct

Tags: arrays, string, initialization, solidity

I am currently working on my first smart contract. After already reading a few topics out there I still don't have a clue on how to initialize the string array inside my struct.

The idea is that the customer can always choose from a variety of energysources on a homepage which then gets deployed on the smart contract if he's done choosing.

So what would be the best/efficient way to implement this idea onto the blockchain?

```
         pragma solidity ^0.4.23; /* solhint-disable */

         contract EnergyContract {


           struct EnContract {
             uint price;
             uint amount;
             string[] energysource;
             address creator;   
           }

           EnContract[] aContract;

           function createContract(uint _price, uint _amount, address _creator) public {
             aContract.length += 1;
             EnContract storage _EnContract = aContract[aContract.length - 1];

             _EnContract.price = _price;
             _EnContract.amount = _amount;
             _EnContract.creator = _creator;    
           }


         }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you declare your array is correct. You don't need to do anything else. You can just start pushing data into the array.